# What is the Python equivalent of Ruby's "inspect"?

Tags: python

I just want to quickly see the properties and values of an object in Python, how do I do that in the terminal on a mac (very basic stuff, never used python)?

Specifically, I want to see what `message.attachments` are in [this Google App Engine MailHandler example](http://pastie.org/680280) (images, videos, docs, etc.).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use the `getmembers` attribute of the `inspect` module

It will return a list of `(key, value)` tuples. It gets the value from `obj.__dict__` if available and uses `getattr` if the the there is no corresponding entry in `obj.__dict__`. It can save you from writing a few lines of code for this purpose.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to dump the entire object, you can use the [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module to get a pretty-printed version of it.

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(my_object)

# If there are many levels of recursion, and you don't want to see them all
# you can use the depth parameter to limit how many levels it goes down
pprint(my_object, depth=2)
```

Edit: I may have misread what you meant by 'object' - if you're wanting to look at class instances, as opposed to basic data structures like dicts, you may want to look at the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module instead.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

There are better ways to do this than `dir`. See other answers.

**Original Answer**

Use the built in function [`dir(fp)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) to see the attributes of `fp`.

Comment: great thank you, now I can just loop through those and print `key = object[value]` (key = value). is there a better way?

Comment: I cannot think of another way expect perhaps `getattr`, another built in function.

Comment: There are better ways, but if you're just poking around in the console, trying to get an idea of what options are available on a particular object/module, `dir` is a nice quick, simple one-liner that doesn't require any imports or anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
repr(obj) # returns a printable representation of the given object
```

or

```
dir(obj) # the list of object methods
```

or

```
obj.__dict__ # object variables
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one else has mentioned Python's `__str__` method, which provides a string representation of an object. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to print automatically in pdb.

One can also use `__repr__` for that, but `__repr__` has other requirements: for one thing, you are (at least in theory) supposed to be able to `eval()` the output of `__repr__`, though that requirement seems to be enforced only rarely.

Comment: +1 for Python's `__repr__` as an equivalent to Ruby's `.inspect`. I think that Python's `__str__` is more of an equivalent to Ruby's `.to_s`.

Answer (score 0):

Or unify Abrer and Mazur answers and get:

```py
from pprint import pprint
pprint(my_object.__dict__ )
```